# Can cl:loop use a custom sum function?

Tags: loops, common-lisp

Can I specify a custom summing function (e.g., `vector-add`) for a loop?

I want to do things like this:

```
(loop for vec in '((1 2) (3 4)) sum vec)
;=> (4 6)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an interesting question.  It would be nice if you could do this, but short answer is “no.”  According to [6.1.3 Value Accumulation Clauses](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/06_ac.htm) from the HyperSpec:

> The `sum` construct forms a cumulative sum of the successive *primary values*
>    of the supplied *form* at each iteration. The argument *var* is
>   used to accumulate the sum; if *var* is supplied, [**loop**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_loop.htm#loop) does not return
>   the final sum automatically. The *var* argument is bound as if by the
>   construct `with` to a zero of the appropriate type. Subsequent values
>   (including any necessary coercions) are computed as if by the *function*
>   **`+`**. If `into` *var* is used, a *type* can be supplied for *var* with the *type-spec* argument; the consequences are unspecified if a nonnumeric
>   *type* is supplied. If there is no `into` variable, the optional *type-spec*
>   argument applies to the internal variable that is keeping the sum. The
>   default *type* is *implementation-dependent*; but it must be a *supertype*
>   of *type* **number**.

Is your actual use case this simple (looping through a list and computing a vector sum of them) or is it more complex?  If it's about this simple, you can do what you want with [`reduce`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_reduce.htm).  It would look more of less like

```
(reduce 'vector-add '((1 2) (3 4)))
```

where `vector-add` is your custom summing function.  If you still need to use `loop`, you can get `reduce`-like behavior using `for sum = ... then ...` in the `loop` and an explicit `finally (return sum)`.  First, with a definition of `vector-add`,

```
(defun vector-add (x y)
  (mapcar '+ x y))

(vector-add '(1 2) '(3 4))
;=> (4 6)
```

we can do:

```
(loop
   for vec in '((1 2) (3 4) (5 6))
   for sum = vec then (vector-add sum vec)
   finally (return sum))
;=> (9 12)
```

Comment: I'm already doing the reducing thing. The short-coming is that the whole list has to be collected first and then reduced.

Comment: OK, with the code that's in the question, the whole list is already collected.  Can you elaborate on the example a bit?  (But _thank you_ for providing a simplified example to start with;  it's frustrating when people paste a "Wall-of-Code".)  Is the loop also responsible for generating the individual vectors?

Comment: @SaltyEgg I've updated the answer to include an example of how `loop` can be used in a `reduce`-like fashion.  If you're using `loop` to generate the individual addends, then you can use `for sum = x then (vector-add sum x)` to accumulate the sum, but you'll also need to explicitly `return` it at the end.

Comment: Since Common Lisp implementations don't necessarily implement tail-call elimination, it's also an efficient way to implement `reduce`. :)

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with `iterate` library:

```
(ql:quickload "iterate")

(use-package :iterate)

(defun vector-add (x y) (mapcar '+ x y))

(iter (for i in '((1 2) (3 4))) (reducing i by #'vector-add)) ; (4 6)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another way to customize summing besides using a special summing function with the `for ... = ... then ...` clause is to use the `sum ... into ...` clause:

```
(loop for (n1 n2) in '((1 2) (3 4))
   sum n1 into s1
   sum n2 into s2
   finally (return (list s1 s2)))
```

Comment: This is a solution for `vector-add`, but can not generalized to other non-arithmetic operations.